# Is it possible for a file in any OS to not be in any folder?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, directory, root

I am studying for my A+ exam and I wanted to get some clarification about how files are stored.

My understanding is that in Windows, storage of all files starts at the root of the drive, whether it be C: or D: etc..., but all files are on one of these drives, either in a subfolder of the lettered drive or directly in C: or D: etc.

In macOS and Linux, there is a root directory: "/." All mass storage devices are mounted by the OS to act as subfolders of /, usually mounted to a single folder called /mount or /media in Linux and /Volumes in macOS.

If this is true, is it possible for a file to be stored outside of a folder in either scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak about Windows, but on unix-like OSes (macOS, Linux, BSD, etc) and filesystems it's sort-of possible for a file to exist without being in a folder.

In a traditional unix-like filesystem, a directory is essentially a list of filenames and the inodes numbers that hold the actual files. The same inode number can be listed in multiple directories and/or under multiple names in the same directory. These directory entries are called "links" to the file. You can create additional directory entries (links) to a file with the `ln` command. Here's a quick demo:

```
$ echo "This is a file" >afile.txt
$ ln afile.txt anotherlink.txt
$ ls -li
total 16
152165199 -rw-r--r--  2 gordon  staff  15 Feb 17 16:57 afile.txt
152165199 -rw-r--r--  2 gordon  staff  15 Feb 17 16:57 anotherlink.txt
```

This is not showing two files, this is showing two directory entries that both refer to the same file. Note that the inode number (shown because of the `-i` option to `ls`) is the same, and the link count (just before my username) is 2.

If you "delete" a file (with `rm` or something like that), it doesn't necessarily actually delete the file. For instance:

```
$ rm afile.txt
$ ls -li
total 8
152165199 -rw-r--r--  1 gordon  staff  15 Feb 17 16:57 anotherlink.txt
$ cat anotherlink.txt 
This is a file
```

Note that one directory entry got removed, and the link count is down to 1, but the file's still there.

When you remove the last directory entry to a file, the link count will drop to 0, and the file will actually be deleted... *unless it's open*. Files don't actually get deleted until the link count hits zero, *and* there are no open file handles referring to the file. Here's a demo of opening the file, unlinking it, and then accessing the file through the open file handle:

```
$ exec 3<> anotherlink.txt   # Open the file on FD #3
$ rm anotherlink.txt 
$ cat /dev/fd/3
This is a file
```

...so at this point, a have a file (inode #152165199) that still exists on disk and is accessible, but isn't listed in any directory (and therefore is difficult to access except through that open file handle).

As soon as I close that file handle, the file will actually get deleted.